# Left thumb pain from using Xbox One Controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, health

I was playing *Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare* on my Xbox One. The problem is that after some time (50 mins+), my left thumb started to hurt. I kept on playing, and even after stopping, my thumb kinda hurts now.

How do I play (or how do I use the controller) while avoid getting hurt? In the past when I used PS2 controllers there was no pain and I use my PC for countless hours and never experienced any pain. I think am just using the controller incorrectly, how do I avoid this pain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I really think it's a combination of overuse of your thumbs (~an hour) and the unfamiliar controller that's doing you in, causing "Gamer's Thumb". You said that you used Playstation controllers before, with no issue. Playstation controllers are a fair bit smaller, and a bit different in terms of layout compared to Xbox controllers (namely the left thumbstick and D-pad are switched).

This would probably cause discomfort after a while, as you're not as familiar with this controller as you are with a PS controller. So, like in [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/892/how-can-i-play-without-breaking-my-thumbs), give it a break, then come back to it after a while.

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out that I was applying too much pressure no the buttons :P

Comment: Hand exercises before hand will help, also you can buy smaller wired controllers for about $60AU, bit more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

I find that it is the ring around the thumb grips. On *Call of Duty* games, I spam the sprint button excessively, and the rim design of the controller starts to rub my thumb after a while.

I filled the hollows partly in with BluTac, that helped relieve the contact points a lot by spreading them out over a larger area.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out! That's the reason why my thumb hurts, trying to sprint in COD especially with Exos. the PS4 controller would had been better for this type of play :P but oh well I like the Xbox :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cure!  I found a magnetic connect leveraging system at the game developers expo.  I had serious gamers thumb that almost made me give up on gaming altogether. It's from thumbglovepro.Com and relieved my pain almost instantly. There is no pushing down anymore which after reading up on it(gamers thumb/repetitive stress ingury) seems to be most of the problem.  My game also went up and there is no more slippage or stutter.  I met the owner in person and later got the accessory kit that had elevators and a d pad toggle kit in it. It's been a couple months and I can't play without it. It put me back in the game.

Comment: Thanks for the response! :D but I found out that all I needed was a little bit  more practice using the controller to that point that I just adjusted to it :P =^.^=

Answer (score 0):

I had to quit Xbox one, and played Fifa predominantly. I had to give it a break after massive discomfort on my left thumb. I think it has much to do with the controller, lots to do with repetition, and even more todo with genetics. (Strength of grip, etc.) I won a PS4 @ D&B and played %60 percent of matches than before with my Xbox. The tired, achy thumb(s) was much improved

Now I’ve been drawn back to Xbox bc of Fifa and old online mates. I’m already worn down on the thumb front. I think I’d I shall continue, I will try that goofy ass thumbpro.com thing. And maybe a secondary controller.

#blessed